# How to run AWS Glue Crawler after resource update/created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I have defined a resource in my Terraform to create a Glue Crawler that I don't want to schedule. But I want it to run after being created and updated. I couldn't find anything in the documentation about how to trigger this.

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "my_crawler" {
  database_name = "my_db"
  name          = "my_crawler"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/service-role/someRole"

  s3_target {
    path = "s3://my_bucket/key/prefix"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a [`local-exec` provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to use the AWS CLI to trigger your Glue crawler once it is created:

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "my_crawler" {
  database_name = "my_db"
  name          = "my_crawler"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/service-role/someRole"

  s3_target {
    path = "s3://my_bucket/key/prefix"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws glue start-crawler --name ${self.name}"
  }
}
```

This would be only triggered when creating the crawler and not at any other point, such as if you changed the `s3_target.path` or anything else.

If you wanted to be able to trigger this when changing the `s3_target.path` you'd need to use a [`null_resource` with a `trigger`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html):

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "my_crawler" {
  database_name = "my_db"
  name          = "my_crawler"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/service-role/someRole"

  s3_target {
    path = "s3://my_bucket/key/prefix"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "run_crawler" {
  # Changes to the crawler's S3 path requires re-running
  triggers = {
    s3_path = "${aws_glue_crawler.my_crawler.s3_target.0.path}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws glue start-crawler --name ${aws_glue_crawler.my_crawler.name}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The local-exec provisioner worked! And many thanks about the extra information on how to trigger a crawler when s3 patch changed.

Answer (score 0):

If terraform is part of ci/cd, you can write shell/python script to run crawler after it is deployed